# mui-datatables filter from outside

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I am trying to set a filter from outside the mui-datatable.  I would like to pass in the value of the filter from actions outside of the table. For example click a button which has a preset filter. Is there an api to take an external event and change the filter state of the table?

```
...

    const options = {
      filter: true,
      selectableRows: 'multiple',
      filterType: 'dropdown',
      responsive: 'vertical',
      rowsPerPage: 10,

      //* pass filter somehow here
      receiveSomeFilter:this.state.tableFilter
    };
    const ageFilter = (age)=> {
        this.setState({tableFilter:age})
    }

    return (
        <div>
        <Button onClick = {ageFilter(28)}>Filter by age 28</Button>
      <MUIDataTable title={"ACME Employee list"} data={data} columns={columns} options={options} />
      </div>
    );

  }
}

export default Example;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  This forum is unique for its ability to help you out with specific code problems, but we can be more helpful if you post code segments and other things that you have tried.  The answers will generally become much more focused and useful if we see what isn't working.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up filtering from the outside by updating the options for each column, and updating the `filterList` array of the column's options.

A simple example ([CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-fermat-gzphf?file=/src/App.tsx:23-1388))

```js
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import { Select, MenuItem } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const initCols = [
    {
      name: "name",
      label: "Name",
      options: {
        filterList: []
      }
    }
  ];
  const [cols, setCols] = useState(initCols);
  const [selectedFilter, setSelectedFilter] = useState("All");

  const data = [
    { name: "Joey Tribbiani" },
    { name: "Phoebe Buffay" },
    { name: "Rachel Green" },
    { name: "Ross Geller" },
    { name: "Monica Geller" },
    { name: "Chandler Bing" }
  ];

  const onFilter = ({ target: { value } }: any) => {
    setSelectedFilter(value);
    const filteredCols = [...cols];
    let filterList = [];
    if (value !== "All") {
      filterList = [value];
    }
    // Target the column to filter on.
    filteredCols[0].options.filterList = filterList;
    setCols(filteredCols);
  };

  const options = {
    filter: false
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select onChange={onFilter} value={selectedFilter}>
        <MenuItem value="All">All</MenuItem>
        {data.map((x) => (
          <MenuItem key={x.name} value={x.name}>
            {x.name}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
      <MUIDataTable
        title="Filter"
        columns={cols}
        data={data}
        options={options}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The key is in the `onFilter` function, which is the `onChange` listener for my external control (a Select in this case). You need to update the appropriate column's `options.filterList` to an Array containing the exact value that a row might have for that column.  That `filterList` can contain multiple values, hence the Array. Set it an empty Array to remove filtering for that column. And of course you need to `useState` to control the columns, otherwise it won't update.

Comment: This worked. i was able to set the filter this way. thank you so much :)

Comment: Is it possible to update the filters without doing a complete rerender? Because when I update the filters from the standard filterMenu, it won't do a complete rerender of my whole page (only the table gets updated/rerendered). I searched the Documentation for maybe a "updateFilters" function or something similar but I couldn't find anything :(