# Filtered Data in MUIDatatables

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

How can I access the filtered data in muidatatables. I want to perform few operations on that outside the toolbar. How can I do it?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65853084/5566935)

Comment: @MohammadAbdulAlim I dont want to filter from outside . I want the filtered data in muidatatable ....as a variable or something so that i can use it for my operations.